# Receiving notification from Mail and Messages, but no snippets

Tags: iphone, messages, notifications, mobile-mail

When I first got my iPhone, I disabled receiving notifications from Mail and Messages apps on the lock screen and the notification center, because these apps display snippets of received messages in those locations and anyone could see them without a password. (Since most people send short emails and messages these days, the snippets are practically the whole messages.) I left the sound notification and the banner enabled.

Yesterday, I saw someone else's iPhone: He still received notifications from Messages but the notification read: "You have a new message!"

That's perfect! I want that too. But no matter how much I searched, I didn't find any setting that enables me to do this. Web search was a complete waste of time.

Does anyone know how to conceive such a thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a setting in *Settings*, *Notifications*, *Messages* at the very bottom: "Show Previews".

Toggling it would disable previews for Messages. Such a setting, however, is not available for Mail.